Custom CSS Scrollbar for different operating systems and browsers
I found a similar question, where really working approaches are indicated to fix the scrollbar display in Firefox and Chrome.
However, on other systems, especially Windows 11 for Firefox (125), this scroll bar takes on a different behavior, making it unclear that the segment can be scrolled.
(Screenshots are attached at the end)
Behavior problems for Windows 11 (there may be other systems with a similar problem, but others have not been tested):

The scroll slider appears when you hover over the element in which it should be located
The background for the scroll bar does not appear
More or less the required view can be acquired only by clicking on the scroll slider

Are there any possible solutions to the problem? In an article on Habr they talk about special default settings specifically for Windows 11 + Firefox Always show scroll bars, but is it possible to set the desired styles regardless of this setting?
On Windows 10 versions of both Firefox and Chrome, the following code works as expected.
@supports (scrollbar-color: auto) and (not selector(::-webkit-scrollbar)) {
    ul {
      scrollbar-color: #bebebe #eaeaea;
      scrollbar-width: thin;
    }
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #bebebe;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: none;
}

In the first photo there is no mouse on the ul element

In the second photo I hovered the mouse over the ul element and got a slider

In the third photo I'm pulling the slider

The fourth photo shows the expected result (default)

